# How to define default field value from another field (from another model)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I have a model with 2 fields. This is a wizard.

```
class SalaryEquivalence(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'wizard.salary.equivalence'

    salary_type = fields.Selection(
        [('brute', 'Brute'),
        ('liquid','Líquid'),
        ('base','Base')],
        string='Type', default='base')
    salary = fields.Float('Salary')
```

The idea is that when I open the wizard, the salary field on form will have an specific value. This value will depend on the 'wage' field from 'hr.contract'.
The wizard will open from a button on 'hr.contract' form, so I'm able to get the active_id.

Also, the field must be editable, it has to show the default value only when I open the wizard.

Thanks.

Comment: If you need to pass the wage value to the wizard when you click on the button, add the default value in the button context like the following: `context="{'default_wage': wage}"`

Comment: @Kenly works perfect, thanks!